# Combine list of lists with named indices in Map-like structure

Tags: haskell

I have a program with two data structures I wish to combine.  The use of `Data.Map` here is incidental because I'm using it elsewhere for a related purpose.  If a solution never uses `Data.Map`, that's fine (probably better). I've simplified the problem to the below script that has all the essential elements.

My actual program is in a different domain, but in the analogy various "interviewers" are assigned to interview all the people in given households (named by index position of the "house").  I would like to determine which interviewers will need to conduct multiple interviews.

If an interviewer is assigned multiple households, she automatically must interview multiple people (in the scenario, all households are occupied).  However, if she is assigned only one household, she might also need to interview the several people there.

The initial wrong approach I found (misled by my wrong assumption about the domain) produces the result below.  However, I'm having trouble formulating the correct solution. For my purpose, the order in which the interviews occur in the result is not important.

```hs
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

-- Create Map from list of pairs, making dup vals into a list
fromListWithDuplicates :: Ord k => [(k, v)] -> Map k [v]
fromListWithDuplicates pairs =
    Map.fromListWith (++) [(k, [v]) | (k, v) <- pairs]

data Person = Person {
    name :: String
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

households = [[Person "Alice", Person "Bob"],
              [Person "Carlos"],
              [Person "Dabir", Person "Eashan"],
              [Person "Fatima"] ]

interviewers = [("Agent1", [0]), ("Agent2", [1,2]), ("Agent3", [3])]

multiInterviewsWRONG households interviewers =
    let assignments = [(agent, name person) |
                       (agent, houseIndices) <- interviewers,
                       index <- houseIndices,
                       person <- (households !! index),
                       length houseIndices > 1 ]
    in Map.assocs $ fromListWithDuplicates assignments

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- Prints: [("Agent2", ["Eashan","Dabir","Carlos"])]
    putStrLn $ show (multiInterviewsWRONG households interviewers)

    -- Correct: [("Agent2", ["Eashan","Dabir","Carlos"]),
    --           ("Agent1", ["Alice","Bob"]]
```

---

Followup: this solution is just Willem Van Onsem's below, but putting it in one place:

```hs
import Util (lengthExceeds)
multiInterviews households interviewers =
    let assignments = [(agent, name person) |
                       (agent, houseIndices) <- interviewers,
                       index <- houseIndices,
                       person <- (households !! index) ]
    in filter (flip lengthExceeds 1 . snd)
        (Map.assocs $ fromListWithDuplicates assignments)
```

Comment: The `length houseIndices > 1` will only retain agents with two or more households.

Comment: Quite true. That was the conceptual error I first had (it was embedded in a more complex overall program, so not quite so obvious in this simplification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `length houseIndices > 1` constraints, since that means that it will only retain agents, given they have to interview two or more households. You thus should use as list comprehension:

```
multiInterviews households interviewers =
    let assignments = [
        (agent, name person) |
        (agent, houseIndices) <- interviewers,
        index <- houseIndices,
        person <- households !! index
      ]
    # …
```

The given list comprehension will produce a list that looks like:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| [
Prelude|         (agent, name person) |
Prelude|         (agent, houseIndices) <- interviewers,
Prelude|         index <- houseIndices,
Prelude|         person <- households !! index
Prelude|       ]
Prelude| :}
[("Agent1","Alice"),("Agent1","Bob"),("Agent2","Carlos"),("Agent2","Dabir"),("Agent2","Eashan"),("Agent3","Fatima")]
```

We however need to filter, we can look at the `assocs` with lists that contain at least two items. We can implement an efficient function to determine if the list has at least two items:

```
atLeastTwo :: [a] -> Bool
atLeastTwo (_:_:_) = True
atLeastTwo _ = False
```

and apply this filter to the `assocs` of the `Map`:

```
multiInterviews households interviewers =
    let assignments = …
    in filter (atLeastTwo . snd) (Map.assocs (fromListWithDuplicates assignments))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I knew the constraint was wrong, and that I'd probably want to filter the larger list, but was blocking on the details (I've stared at it way too long).

Is your `atLeastTwo` actually more efficient than `filter ((> 1) . length . snd)`? In one run of a macro benchmark, yours was 42 seconds vs 41 for the point-free style, but there is a jitter of about 2 seconds from run to run, so that doesn't mean anything (and that operation can't really contribute much to the time, in any case).

Comment: @DavidMertz: if the list is long, or infinite, `length` runs in *O(n)*, whereas `atLeastTwo` runs in *O(1)*. For long lists, there is thus a computation gain, although the total algorithm will still take *O(n^2)* because of the appending of the lists.

Comment: It thus might be better to look for a solution where you edit the `HashMap` by key, and thus prepend the list with one item. This is computationally more efficient than first making singleton lists, and then appending, since `(++)` is linear in the length of the first sublist.

Comment: GHC isn't smart enough to know that it doesn't need to fully compute `length` to find, e.g. `length millionItems > 3`?

Comment: @DavidMertz: no, it is not, or at least not as far as I know, but based on the benchmarks of lists with a lot of items, it is not. There are libraries that export `lengthExceeds`, `lengthAtMost`, etc. that thus stop once it knows if the length is greater than/... a given length, like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-8.10.2/docs/Util.html#v:lengthExceeds

Comment: Yup! You are quite right, of course.  I'm mildly disappointed and surprised that this program hangs:

    let infList = [1..]; 
    forM_ [100,99..1] (\len ->
        putStrLn $ "Infinite is longer than" ++ show len ++ ": " ++ show (length infList > len))

Comment: If I modify the program to a 100 item list to compare, it takes about a 1/100th of a second, and for a million item list, about 1/2 second.  So indeed, that's going to be linear, more-or-less (discounting startup overhead, etc.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236863/discussion-between-david-mertz-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 3):

Obviously Willem's answer is great, but I think it can't hurt to also offer one without a list comprehension:

```hs
atLeastTwo :: [a] -> Bool
atLeastTwo (_:_:_) = True
atLeastTwo _ = False

transformSnd :: (b -> c) -> (a, b) -> (a, c)
transformSnd fun (f, s) = (f, fun s)
-- or transformSnd = second (from Control.Arrow; h/t Willem)
-- or transformSnd = fmap (from (,)'s Functor instance; h/t Will Ness)
-- or transformSnd = second (from Data.Bifunctor)

mult :: [(String, [String])]
mult = filter (atLeastTwo . snd) . map (transformSnd toInterviewees) $ interviewers
  where toInterviewees = map name . concatMap (households !!)

-- mult == [("Agent1",["Alice","Bob"]),("Agent2",["Carlos","Dabir","Eashan"])]
```

I'm *reasonably* sure the two versions run equally fast; which one is more readable depends on who's doing the reading.

There are a couple of functional differences. First, with Willem's answer, you get a map, while with this one you get a list (but the difference is mainly cosmetic, and you said you didn't care much).

Second, the two versions behave differently if there are two pairs in the `interviewers` list that have the same first element. Doing it Willem's way will do what you probably want, i. e. treat them as one pair with a longer second element; doing it this way will give you two pairs in the result list which have the same first element.

Also, you probably know this, but: if you find yourself combining lists a lot, you might want sets instead.

Comment: Your `transformSnd` is in fact a function defined in the base, it is equivalent to `second` from the `Control.Arrow` module. You are right it is not in the `Prelude`, but it is available from the `base` package.

Comment: `transformSnd` is shorter spelled `fmap`.